# Do Spring (Java framework) questions inherently get less attention? Or are my questions bad?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I've been around long enough to provide enough detail and never had trouble getting answers to my questions before using the Spring framework.

But my questions about Spring seem to draw a lot less attention than my 'regular' coding questions. Is it just hard to get Spring questions answered here? Could it just be a matter of having a lack of Spring experts active here? Or are my questions not detailed enough or too detailed/headachy-sounding?

My latest example of this is ['Invalid bean definition' when migrating Spring Boot 2.0.6 to 2.1.0 with EvaluationContextExtensionSupport and custom PermissionEvaluator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410526/invalid-bean-definition-with-when-migrating-spring-boot-2-0-6-to-2-1-0-with-ev) but I've had others that hardly drew attention. This one in particular is worse since even with a bounty it's not getting any relevant answers.

Some older questions that never were answered, although I did finally find some workaround or dropped the component entirely:

- [Spring Boot @PreAuthorize expression not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684452/spring-boot-preauthorize-expression-not-working)
- [Using EntityManager while in full integration test doesn't commit changes in time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174368/using-entitymanager-while-in-full-integration-test-doesnt-commit-changes-in-tim)
- [QueryDsl ignoring predicate when using another @Query annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312780/querydsl-ignoring-predicate-when-using-another-query-annotation)

Comment: Not enough contributors, only 1 in 3 questions get an answer.  Ideally users stop using SO when they can't get help anymore, fixing the disparity a bit, but that's not [what's happening](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=spring%2Cspring-boot).  Most notable about both tags is that users barely get helpful votes, most active user only gets a measly ~0.5 vote per post.  And all the experts have left the building.  Hallmarks of a dead tag community, so what you see is pretty normal.  A bounty is the only practical workaround.

Comment: I know nothing about Spring, but I gotta tell you; questions whose titles are the text of an exception are usually the least interesting to answer; I tend to avoid them like the plague.

Comment: There comes a point in your career where your questions on Stack Overflow will start to receive less attention. Not because they're bad questions but because they're exceptionally good questions, needing very detailed expertise to answer. You yourself are clearly an expert on the subject and thus the questions you ask are beyond the many. Getting the eyes of someone who might know the answer into your question involves  many things... mostly luck.

Comment: This is, I believe, because many new users are scared away by the flags. By the time they have gathered enough knowledge to be useful, they have already migrated to a platform such as reddit where they can interact without fear of being made to feel dumb. So is the nature of our platform: zero-sum. The same things that reward experience can punish a lack thereof. Yesterday's noobs weere supposed to be todays answerers.

Answer (score 3):

These questions are all pretty specific and localized. General questions tend to get more attention and answers because there are more people that can answer them (everyone that can answer Spring questions has a general understanding of Java, the reverse is not true).

If I were to give a point for improvement, especially the 2nd question in the list is pretty text-heavy: you start with a section of code and immediately follow it with a large paragraph expressing how your application should behave, how it's behaving now, and different considerations for how to fix it.

This is also sort-of true for your 3rd question in the list. Your 1st one in the list seems properly written to me, and also has 253 views, so I don't know why that hasn't gotten any useful replies.

You could try to split out separate points in separate paragraphs to increase readability. Personally, I'd need to read a paragraph like that a couple of times, and I just skip questions that are difficult to read on busy days, since I don't want to invest the effort.

As for your bountied question, most activity seems to occur when the bounty is about to expire. Also, someone has attempted to answer it, but unfortunately couldn't help you. I wouldn't count that as a fail just yet.

Answer (score 3):

Working in Spring Boot now, I think your question is just ***fine***.  You couldn't improve on it in the hopes of attracting another answerer.

In general, since Spring is so vast, someone with the precise expertise you're looking for may be harder to come by than you realize.  I work in Spring Boot, but in a limited capacity (mostly these days with Apache Camel), so I would not be of much value to you as an answerer.

The only thing you could do (which you have done) is add a bounty to the question.  Hopefully for your sake, this attracts people who know a thing or two instead of people willing to *guess*.